# MongoDb with .NET driver server-side validation of manual client-side field encryption

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am implementing manual client-side encryption of specific properties in my document. The [MongoDB documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/csfle/reference/server-side-schema/) suggests that I can specify a schema that can be used to carry out server-side validation, I'm trying to set this up in order to ensure that the properties are correctly encrypted by the client code.

I'm specifying the schema when the collection is being created.

```
var schemaMap = new Dictionary<string, BsonDocument> { { collectionNamespace.CollectionName, schema } };

var options = new AutoEncryptionOptions(
    keyVaultNamespace,
    kmsProviders,
    schemaMap: schemaMap,
    bypassAutoEncryption: true);

var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
settings.AutoEncryptionOptions = options;
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
var encryptedDatabase = client.GetDatabase(collectionNamespace.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName);
encryptedDatabase.CreateCollection(collectionNamespace.CollectionName);
```

And then again when creating the MongoDB Client that is used to `Insert` the documents.

```
var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString);
var autoEncryptionOptions = new AutoEncryptionOptions(
    
    keyVaultNamespace: keyVaultNamespace,
    kmsProviders: kmsProviders,
    schemaMap: schemaMap,
    bypassAutoEncryption: true
    );
clientSettings.AutoEncryptionOptions = autoEncryptionOptions;
var secureClient = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
```

When I then insert a document that intentionally **doesn't** comply with the configured schema, there is no exceptions thrown to identify the issue.

```
secureCollection.InsertOne(sampleDocument);
```

The schema being used is based on the [MongoDB example code](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/csfle/quick-start/#create-an-encryption-schema-for-your-collection)

I'm working with a Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB account, server version 4.2. The MongoDB.Driver version is 2.20.0.

Have I mis-understood what the schema validation is capable of doing? Or have  I missed a step?

Any pointers would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See below:

1. When you set `bypassAutoEncryption=true`, then you skip all encryption logic, so only decryption could happen if the field was encrypted previously.
2. "there is no exceptions thrown to identify the issue." - it's expected, the only goal of `schemaMap` is to provide a path to the encrypted field, it doesn't validate the document and if the path leads to not existed field - then the whole encryption logic is skipped.
3. "a Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB account, server version 4.2. The MongoDB.Driver version is 2.20.0." - I'm not 100% sure whether CSFLE (version 1) logic even can work with cosmosdb. At the very least you should spawn mongocryptd daemon from mongo (not cosmos) server binaries and I will not be surprised if it's not the only question in this case. Also, a newly released queryable encryption (CSFLE version 2) definitely won't work with cosmos since it includes server workflow

Comment: Thanks for explaining the usage of `schemaMap` I'd missed that. Having re-read the documentation around schema validation, it would appear that setting a `Validator` in the `CreateCollectionOptions` is the correct approach (although I've not yet got it working).

Using the explicit encryption, we are able to get encrypted data into the CosmosDB and have it auto-decrypted on retrieval.

Comment: explicit encryption doesn't require spawning `mongocryptd` daemon, but auto encryption requires

Comment: the only required steps you can find here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Examples/ClientEncryptionExamples.cs#L72, but it assumes that a path to mongocryptd is added to PATH env variable

Comment: One of the limitations of using  CosmosDB with the API for MongoDB is that Automatic encryption isn't supported [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-42#client-side-field-level-encryption).  Explicit decryption and automatic decryption is supported, this is why I'm trying to add server-side schema validation, to ensure that the required properties are encrypted when documents are Inserted.

Comment: what you want is not really clear from the initial question, but if this is what your goal is, then yes, it should work. NOTE: pay attention that you specify collectionName incorrectly in schemaMap

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the original attempt at schema validation using `AutoEncryptionOptions` was incorrect (as helpfully pointed out by @dododo) further investigation into how to implement server-side schema validation led to defining a `Validator` when creating a Collection.

```
    encryptedDatabase.CreateCollection(
        collectionNamespace.CollectionName,
        new CreateCollectionOptions<Student>
        {
            Validator = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Student>().JsonSchema(schemaDocument)
        });
```

This approach still didn't work, but this is due to the database being used, rather than the implementation.The solution being worked on is using the MongoDB API to access an Azure CosmosDB. An answer from Microsoft states that this functionality isn't supported by CosmosDB

> We got info from our team - Cosmos DB doesn’t support schema validation

Closer examination of the Microsoft  [Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB vs MongoDB Atlas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/cosmos-db-vs-mongodb-atlas#azure-cosmos-db-for-mongodb-vs-mongodb-atlas) documentation reveals that 'JSON schema for data governance controls' is 'Currently in development'